# C# and VB.NET raise event differences

Tags: c#

I have a question.. in VB.NET I'd have this sub, for example:

```
Sub AcceptClient(ByRef pSocket As Socket)
'Some Code...
End Sub
```

And then, I'd have this, to call it whenever the event is raised:

```
AddHandler mAcceptor.OnAccepted, AddressOf AcceptClient
```

However, in C#, when I do this, using the following code:

```
mAcceptor.OnAccepted += acceptClient();
void acceptClient(Socket pSocket)
```

It says I'm missing the pSocket argument. But, in VB.NET, It works flawlessly. Why's that? I tried adding "ref", that didn't do the trick. What else can I do to solve this?.. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

```
acceptClient()
```

would call a method `acceptClient` with no arguments and return a result. What you want is to add the method as an event handler:

```
mAcceptor.OnAccepted += acceptClient;
```

Note the lack of parentheses; you're using the method instead of calling it.